# Caught exception Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-bin.zip'

Tags: java, spring, gradle, grails, liquibase

I am running the command dbm-gorm-diff to add columns to a table using Liquibase. When i run the command, I get the error:

| Error Caught exception Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-bin.zip'.

here is my gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Mon Mar 15 08:44:17 EAT 2021
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-bin.zip
```

Below is my gradle.properties

```
grailsVersion=3.2.3
gradleWrapperVersion=3.0
```

And below is the log

```
grails> dbm-gorm-diff  
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE                                                          
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE                                                   
:buildProperties UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE      
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:findMainClass
:dbmGormDiff                 
ERROR grails.boot.config.tools.ClassPathScanner - The application defines a Groovy source using the default package. Please move all Groovy sources into a package.

> Building 85% > :dbmGormDiff
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Unknown column 'this_.cell_number' in 'field list'
ERROR grails.plugins.quartz.listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener - Exception occurred in job: Grails Job
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Hibernate operation: could not extract ResultSet; bad SQL grammar [n/a]; nested
exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'this_.cell_number' in 'field list'
        at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:111)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Hibernate operation: could not extract ResultSet; bad SQL grammar [n/a]; nested exception is com.mysql.
jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'this_.cell_number' in 'field list'
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.convertJdbcAccessException(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:668)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.convertHibernateAccessException(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:656)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:247)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:187)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.executeWithNewSession(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:137)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore.withNewSession(AbstractHibernateDatastore.java:320)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.withNewSession(AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:59)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.withNewSession(GormEntity.groovy:999)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$withNewSession$2.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at com.omnitech.mis.User.withNewSession(User.groovy)
        at com.omnitech.mis.User$withNewSession.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at ysave.DrupalUserExportJob.execute(DrupalUserExportJob.groovy:19)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:104)
        ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'this_.cell_number' in 'field list'
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1075)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2834)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2313)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2122)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1905)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1881)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:925)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2622)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2605)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2434)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2429)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1787)
        at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateQuery.listForCriteria(AbstractHibernateQuery.java:700)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateQuery.list(AbstractHibernateQuery.java:690)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindAllByFinder.invokeQuery(FindAllByFinder.java:54)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindAllByFinder$1.doInSession(FindAllByFinder.java:48)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:318)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFinder.execute(AbstractFinder.java:42)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindAllByFinder.doInvokeInternal(FindAllByFinder.java:45)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.invoke(DynamicFinder.java:174)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.invoke(DynamicFinder.java:374)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FinderMethod$invoke$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.methodMissing(GormStaticApi.groovy:173)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.staticMethodMissing(GormEntity.groovy:749)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$staticMethodMissing$4.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at com.omnitech.mis.User.staticMethodMissing(User.groovy)
        at com.omnitech.mis.User$staticMethodMissing$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:214)
        at com.omnitech.mis.User.$static_methodMissing(User.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1501)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1489)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
      
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate$1.doInHibernate(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:140)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:243)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Command execution error: Bean named 'sessionFactory' is expected to be of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean] but was actually of type [org.hibern
ate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl]
:dbmGormDiff FAILED          
              
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dbmGormDiff'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 24.239 secs
| Error Caught exception Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-bin.zip'. (Use --stacktrace to see
 the full trace)
```

I've figured out that I may be helped more if I share my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
        dbmMigrationVersion = '2.0.0.RC4'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:database-migration:$dbmMigrationVersion"
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.5.0"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.0"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "something"

apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"
apply plugin: "java"

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    maven { url "http://jitpack.io"}
    maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
    maven { url  "http://repository.codehaus.org"}
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.kayr:fuzzy-csv:1.6.26'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.2.Final"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.2.Final"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.11.1"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:database-migration:$dbmMigrationVersion"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.8'
    compile 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.6.1'
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:audit-logging:2.0.1'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC1'
    compile 'com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'eu.bitwalker:UserAgentUtils:1.20'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'grails-app/migrations'
        }
    }
}
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

Comment: *Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'this_.cell_number' in 'field list'* Sounds pretty clear

Comment: This exception is caused when the field name specified in the select sql clause does not exists in the database. To resolve this simply fix your SQL select query to use the correct field name that exits in the table or add the missing field as referred in the SQL select query to the database table if it is required. I got this from here (https://www.codercrunch.com/question/768271818/unknown-column-field-list-javalangruntimeexception) but in my case the columns aren't yet in the database. this is the process i have to go through to have them in the database

Comment: Am using this as the guide (https://guides.grails.org/grails-database-migration/guide/index.html) but when i run diff-gorm-diff command, I end up getting that error

Comment: BTW, Gradle 3 is 5 yo, you should get a more recent version

Comment: "BTW, Gradle 3 is 5 yo, you should get a more recent version" - FYI... We shipped Grails 3.2.3 configured with Gradle 3.0.  Gradle 3.0 isn't the cause of this problem.

Comment: then what could be the problem?? the error that shows is; | Error Caught exception Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-bin.zip'. (Use --stacktrace to see
 the full trace)

Answer (score -1):

1. Try using more *recent version* of gradle. May be try using **gradle-4.7-all** or even more latest one
2. Try renaming `c:\users\MY USERNAME\.gradle` directory to `old-.gradle` or deleting `.gradle` directory and then try relaunching the program.

Comment: "Try using more recent version of gradle. May be try using gradle-4.7-all or even more latest one" - I don't think that is going to fix the problem and is likely to cause others.  We shipped Grails 3.2.3 configured with Gradle 3.0. Gradle 3.0 isn't likely to be the cause of this problem.

Comment: "Try renaming c:\users\MY USERNAME\.gradle directory to old-.gradle or deleting .gradle directory and then try relaunching the program." - That isn't going to help.  It looks like the database schema is misaligned with what GORM expects.

Comment: I tried with gradle 6.8.3, gradle 4.7 and gradle 4.0. I ended up with the same error

Comment: I've added my build.gradle to the question as the problem isn't gradle

Comment: Did you check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52564150/grails-could-not-execute-build-using-gradle-distribution-https-services-gra). May be the answers on this post could help.